# Facebook : Show friends faces using the app

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Facebook login plugin that shows profile pictures of friends who are used the same application. For that i tried the following code,

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '***', // App ID
          channelUrl : 'http://www.***.in/', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
       });     
      };
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "js/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
     </script>
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="500" data-max-rows="1"></div> </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine. On login it shows profile pictures of friends who are using the same application. On clicking each foto (profile picture of friend), it navigate to their facebook pages respectively. But my requirement is that, on clicking the foto it should redirect to different url. Is it possible?

Help me please,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On clicking each foto (profile picture of friend), it it navigate to their facebook pages respectively. But my requirement is that, on clicking the foto it should redirect to different url. Is it possible?

No, it’s not.

Like most of the other social plugins, the Login button gets rendered inside an iframe loaded from facebook.com, and the Same Origin Policy prevents you from interacting with content from a different domain via JavaScript.